# write Compute span with stacks in java

Tags: java

I am writing a program for computing spans with stacks
I have written a code and here are the variable I have used in it :

An array of 52 integers named X : this is the array that we want to compute its spans; In this code X elements will be initialized by random function;

The output of this program is An integer Array named S which is in the same size as X ;
and S[i] is the span of the stock on day i

st is a stack.

[image: algorithm is here]
So  here is the code that I have written based on the algorithm:

```
public class ComputingSpansInStack {

static int [] X = new int[52];
static int [] S = new int[52];
public static void SetX()
{

    Random rn = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        X[i] = 1 + rn.nextInt(100);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SetX();
    int h;
    Stack<Integer> st=new MyStack<>();
    boolean done;
    for (int i = 0; i<52 ; i++)
    {
        done = false;

        while(!(st.isEmpty()||done))
                {
                    if(X[i]>= X[st.top()])
                        st.pop();
                    else 
                        done = true;
                }
        if(st.isEmpty())
            h = -1;
        else 
            h = st.top();

        S[i] = i - h;
        st.push(i);  
    }


    for (int i =0; i<52; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(X[i] + "   "+ S[i]);
    }
}
```

but the output is here :

38   ---    1

7 ------  1

16 -----  2

62 ------  4

35 -----  1

31 ----- 1

6  ----- 1
.......

problem:  for 62 It should be 3 not 4;

here is MyStack:

```
public  class MyStack<E> implements Stack<E>{
private final E s[];
int t=0;


public MyStack() {
    this.s = (E[]) new Object[100];
}


public int size(){
    return t;
}


public boolean isEmpty(){
    switch(size()){
        case 0:
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public E top() {
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    return s[t-1];
}

public void push(E element) {
    if(isEmpty())
        s[0]= element;
    else
        s[t]= element;
    t++;
}


public E pop() {
            E x;
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    else{
        x = s[t-1];
        s[t-1] = null;
        t--;
    }
    return x;
}
```

}

any help??

Thanks in advance

Comment: The algorithm looks correct, can you show the implementation of `MyStack`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I have added it to post

Comment: That is a LIFO data structure right? How about `Deque<Integer> st = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();` (Java 6+ required).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly yes, that is.  The question has mentioned to use stacks(LIFO data structures)

Comment: Ok, so replace your custom stack with an `ArrayDeque` and see if it works as expected, if it does I will turn my comment into an answer :).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Why are you talking about deques? The question is about a stack, they are not the same thing.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Queues are FIFO data structures.

Comment: @Hunter and upvoters. From the [Stack javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html):  `A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.`. Just limit the usage of the Deque to the methods you need. It also performs way better than the legacy java Stack, plus does not expose Vector methods (in my humble opinion, exposing queue methods is way less dangerous than exposing Vector methods).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly but a Deque is *not* a stack. deque = double ended queue, which *can* be used as a LIFO data structure but why bother when clearly the algorithm only needs peek, pop, and push. You don't need the additional FIFO stuff that comes along with it.

Comment: Not going to argue here. So you suggest that using a legacy Stack implementation that exposes Vector Methods or a custom home made implementation is a better plan?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Since this is for a class where the students need to implement their own version of Stack, yes I do.

Comment: Nowhere in his question the OP told us that he had to implement his own stack. But if he has to for learning purposes, then I do agree with you. If he does not, I stand for the `Deque`, everytime that professional developers write code using legacy `Stack` implementations or home made fragile collections a pink dolphin dies (seriously!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is correct.  `S[i]` = i + 1 where `X[i]` is greater than all the preceding elements, so since `X[3]` (64) is greater than all the preceding elements, `S[3]` = (3+1) = 4.

In other words, your assumption that `S[3]` should equal 3 is incorrect.  The definition of a span is "the maximum number of consecutive elements `X[j]` immediately preceding `X[i]` and such that
`X[j]` ≤ `X[i]`", but the algorithm appears to add one to the result. For `X[0]` (no immediately preceding smaller elements) it is 1. For `X[1]` (no immediately preceding smaller elements) it is 1.  For `X[2]` (1 immediately preceding smaller element) it is 2.  For `X[3]` (3 immediately preceding smaller elements) it is 4.

This doesn't appear to meet the strict definition of the "maximum", but the algorithm is consistent: if `X[3]` should equal 3, then X[0] and X[1] should equal zero, since there are no immediately preceding smaller elements.

Answer (score 0):

package com.stacks;

public class StockSpan {

```
private int arr[] = { 10, 4, 5, 90, 120, 80 };

public void getSpan() {
    StackImpl s = new StackImpl<Integer>();
    s.push(0);
    int stockSpanRes[] = new int[arr.length];
    stockSpanRes[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        while (!s.isEmpty() && arr[(int) s.peek()] <= arr[i]) {
            s.pop();
        }
        stockSpanRes[i] = s.isEmpty() ? i + 1 : i - (int) s.peek();
        s.push(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(stockSpanRes[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StockSpan s = new StockSpan();
    s.getSpan();

}
```

}

For details, visit https://github.com/ranjeetsinha13/androidcodes/tree/master/DS_Algos/src/com/stacks